# MySQL: ¿Es posible una conexión remota sin tener que autorizar mi dirección IP?

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh, coda

Tengo una base de datos MySQL alojada en un servicio de hosting compartido, o sea, no es un VPS.

Frecuentemente necesito acceder a dicha base de datos desde mi equipo para operar con ella (consultas, inserción, modificación o borrado de datos). Uso Mac OSX Sierra y Coda para tales funciones.

**Para conectar a la BD de forma remota debo antes autorizar mi dirección IP o un rango de direcciones desde mi cuenta de cPanel**. El problema es que antes mi compañía de internet cambiaba poco la dirección IP de mi router... pasaba meses con la misma IP, pero ahora cambia constantemente de IP, incluso varias veces al día. De forma que me encuentro cada dos por tres teniendo que entrar a cPanel a autorizar la nueva IP (y a borrar las anteriores para no tener allí una  lista interminable de IPs autorizadas). Como problema añadido el ISP no asigna IP's en el mismo rango, casi siempre empiezan con números diferentes.

Entonces pregunto, **¿conocen alguna otra forma de conectarse a una base de datos MySQL alojada en hosting compartido que no sea autorizando la dirección IP?** He estado mirando la posibilidad de conectarme a través de llaves públicas y privadas (Coda las acepta para mi conexión ftp), pero en lo que respecta a MySQL no he encontrado nada.

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

**He tratado de hacerlo a través de un túnel ssh, como ha explicado @toledano, pero no doy con ello.** Me da un error del tipo `requested time out`.

---

**NUEVA ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Gracias a las recomendaciones de @MarcosGallardo y de @Toledano he intentando hacer el túnel del modo siguiente:

```
ssh -vvv -f usuario@ip.de.mi.hosting -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N
```

El túnel se hace bien, de acuerdo a la información que sale en pantalla:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving <s>ip.hosting</s> port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <s>ip.hosting</s> [<s>ip.hosting</s>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <s>ip-hosting</s> as '<s>mi-usuario</s>'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/<s>mi-usuario</s>/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <s>mi.ip.remota</s>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
....
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<s>mi-usuario-remoto</s>@<s>mi-ip-remota</s>'s password:
```

Ahora bien, no acepta la llaves privadas que tengo en mi carpeta local `.ssh/` y al final me pida el password, lo ingreso y entra.

Luego desde coda, intento conectar, pero no me deja, me sale el siguiente error:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because the port connection via
>   SSH was refused.
>
> Please ensure that your MySQL host is set up to allow TCP/IP
>   connections (no --skip-networking) and is configured to allow
>   connections from the host you are tunnelling via.
>
> You may also want to check the port is correct and that you have the
>   necessary privileges.
>
> Checking the error detail will show the SSH debug log which may
>   provide more details.
>
> MySQL said: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 0

Esta es la pantalla de conexión desde Coda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de arriba pongo:

- Server: 127.0.0.1 (aquí tengo duda si debo poner mi ip local (198.0.0.... ) he visto en algunos foros que se debe poner la ip del router ¿?
- User name: Mi usuario remoto
- Password: Mi pwd
- Es opcional, lo dejo en blanco

En la parte de abajo:

- SSH Server: La ip de mi server (en vez del nombre del dominio, el cual no es https, la ip si lo es :) )
- User name: Mi usuario remoto
- Password: Mi pwd remota

Pero viendo un problema parecido aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420791/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-using-coda-2 estoy totalmente confundido sobre qué dirección ip hay que poner tanto en la parte de arriba como en la de abajo.

También he leído en algunos foros que hay que poner la dirección ip que me da el router (192.168...) en el archivo .knownhosts de mi dispotivo local, no sé que hay de cierto en eso.

**Conclusión:**

Sospecho que la conexión puede hacerse, pero debe faltar un mínimo detalle que no puedo dar con él. Además, no puedo hacer muchas pruebas, pues sospecho que, cuando hago dos o tres pruebas fallidas, el servidor remoto me bloquea todo intento durante un tiempo (varias horas). Tendré que ir anotando los diferentes intentos hasta dar con el resultado esperado.

Gracias por las sugerencias y si, viendo la nueva información se les ocurre algo, les quedo agradecidos.

Comment: puedes revisar las respuestas de esta pregunta https://stackoverflow/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access

Comment: @BryanVelastegui Gracias, pero lo que se explica en el enlace es la forma de autorizar una dirección IP para que se conecte a la BD y lo que busco es una alternativa a la conexión mediante IP autorizada.

Comment: El error que de `time out` puede deverse a que no tienes SSH en tu servicio, lo que no podrías implementar ni mi alternativa, ni la que propone @Jhd. **¿Podrías confirmar que puedes conectarte a tu host por medio de `ssh`?**

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano ¿haz intentado por medio de una VPN?

Comment: @toledano Sí puedo conectarme. De hecho la conexión FTP se hace usando claves públicas-privadas y alguna vez me he conectado a mysql desde Terminal de Mac OS X, lo que no logro es conectarme desde Coda que es lo que necesito.

Comment: @Jorius No. No sé cómo debería hacer la conexión por VPN e ignoro si de este modo la conexión sería segura. En el blog de Coda sugieren que se haga por SSH, sólo que la explicación es difusa y poco clara.

Comment: @A.Cedano Publique mi respuesta, aunque tienes razón en que la conexión no sería *del todo* segura mediante una VPN, agradecería que te tomaras 5 minutos leyendola, saludos!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Si tienes acceso SSH puedes hacer un túnel. La mayoría de los clientes gráficos pueden hacerlo fácilmente. A grandes rasgos funciona a así.

- Primero te conectas a tu servidor por SSH
- A continuación te conectas a tu base de datos como `localhost`
- La conexión desde y hacia tu equipo remoto se hace a través del puente creado por SSH

Esa opción es bastante segura, puedes usar conexiones usando claves públicas que no involucran contraseñas y todas las conexiones son encriptadas.

Ignoro si Coda puede hacer estas conexiones, pero hay herramientas *open source* que pueden hacerlo (aunque en este momento no recuerdo ninguna).

### Solución

#### Paso 1. Crear un conjunto de claves privadas

Tal como apunta [Jhd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/524/jhd) en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55310/638) es muy conveniente crear un conjunto de llaves pública/privada para aumentar la seguridad de la conexión.

Una vez creada la llave pública, es **muy importante** copiarla en el servidor externo en un archivo llamado `authorized_keys` que en cada conexión revisa el servidor SSHD.

El archivo se encuentra en el directorio `home` del usuario, en la siguiente ruta (siguiendo el ejemplo del OP) que usa un servidor tipo *NIX.

```
 /home/usuario/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Esto aumentará la seguridad de la conexión ya que evitará el uso de la contraseña.

#### 2.1 Creación de un túnel

Con SSH es posible *mapear* un puerto remoto a uno local. Por ejemplo, creas tu conexión con el siguiente comando

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 usuario@servidor.remoto
```

Esto crea el puente entre el puerto local `3307` y el puerto remoto `3306`.

Ahora puedes crear una conexión usando el cliente de MySQL como si fuera un servidor local:

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3307 --user=cedano -p
```

Es infrecuente que un host no permita el *port forwarding*, y si tienes acceso a SSH, esta es tu mejor opción.

En el caso que nos ocupa, que es el uso de Coda, la configuración sería de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2.5 Usando el túnel creado por un programa

Algunos editores, como Coda en este ejemplo y gestores de base de datos, como Navicat o DataGrid de Jetbrains, permiten crear conexiones puente desde el programa, haciendo un poco más fácil este proceso.

Lo que es importante entender es que al usuario un túnel, el servidor remoto, **aparece como local**, por lo tanto todas las conexiones deben referirse al puerto local usado.

Nótese que en el ejemplo de Coda el número de puerto es 3307. En esta alternativa, el puerto de MySQL se refiere **al puerto creado por el túnel**.

#### 3. Autorizar un dominio en cPanel

Como bien apunta [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma) en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56237/638) en el cPanel también es posible autorizar, **además de la IP**, un dominio (en realidad un FQDN, un nombre de dominio completo y calificado), tal como se puede ver en la [documentación de cPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL#).

En el cPanel, se coloca este nombre de dominio, que corresponde a **nuestro equipo local**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servicio mencionado por @Trauma es gratuito y cuenta con una herramienta de actualización automática, que se puede descargar [aquí](https://www.noip.com/download).

También es posible hacerlo en algunos modelos de modems de la suscripción de Internet, como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De este modo, como lo que se autoriza es el dominio, la autorización queda protegida de los cambios de IP, ya que el propio modem o el programa del servicio automáticamente actualizarían estos valores.

---

Observaciones anteriores

Para descartar problemas con Coda o con el *hosting*, te sugiero lo siguiente.

1. Seguir la excelente recomendación que hace @MarcosGallardo de usar otro puerto local. Si tienes instalado MySQL en tu equipo local, es probable que esté usando el mismo puerto. Para evitar conflictos de comunicaciones, crea el puente con otro puerto local.
2. Agrega opciones de depuración para ver que pasa con la conexión, usando las banderas `v`, puedes usar hasta tres para ver con todo detalle la conexión con tu servidor remoto.

   ```
   ssh -vvv -f user@remote.server -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N
   ```
3. Intenta conectarte desde tu cliente, con las modificaciones a la cadena de configuración, por ejemplo:

   ```
   mysql://usuario@contraseña:localhost:3307/base_de_datos
   ```

Una vez realizado lo anterior, si no funciona, deberás asegurar

- con tu proveedor de hosting que lo que deseas sea posible. Todo parece indicar que sí, porque autorizando la IP lo logras,
- con el desarrollador de tu programa, que tenga la capacidad requerida, pero una conexión puente es transparente para los clientes.

Por último, aunque no parece estar relacionado, podrías intentar realizar lo anterior con el firewall de tu equipo desactivado, en el caso de tu modem, coloca tu equipo en la DMZ, consulta los manuales correspondientes.

Comment: Muchas gracias. En cuanto pueda exploraré esa posibilidad y te comentaré el resultado.

Comment: Hola. He intentado lo que dices en la respuesta, pero no me funciona. La primera vez que hice `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 usuario@example.com` me pidió la contraseña, la puse, la aceptó... Luego creé la conexión MySql via SSH en Coda 2 y se conectó, pero cuando borré mi IP de la lista de IPs autorizadas ya dejó de funcionar, da el mensaje: `connect to host deiverbum.org port 22: Operation timed out` (se agota el tiempo de intentos de conexión). He vuelto a autorizar la IP y tampoco funciona. La conexión MySql normal sí, pero la conexión MySQL vía SSH no.

Comment: @A.Cedano, supongo que entonces no se puede, ya sea por cuestiones del programa Coda o por el hosting. Dado que es un problema que no se puede reproducir, la pregunta debería marcarse en ese sentido.

Comment: Yo no me rendiré tan fácilmente. Estoy casi seguro que se puede, pero en algo estoy fallando. Además sospecho que al hacer varios intentos fallidos el servidor remoto me bloquea y no puedo seguir intentando hasta pasadas unas horas (o un día). He agregado información a la pregunta, pues usando el comando como lo sugirió @MarcosGallardo me permitió ver alguna información interesante.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Pensé que al usar el túnel debía usar ese tipo de conexión. Coda me da tres opciones: 1. MySQL Server, 2. MySQL Server vía SSH y 3. MySQL Socket ¿sugieres que use la opción 2? Es con la que me conecto cuando la IP está autorizada, supongo que será esa localhost.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ¡Si Señor! Ha funcionado. Se trataba de la opción 1. He quitado todas las ip remotas autorizadas del cPanel y se conecta. Estaba confundido, pues pensé que debía conectarme usando la opción 2. Quizá desde esa opción se pueda hacer todo, sin tener que hacer el puente previamente. Coda no dice nada al respecto, lo probaré luego. De todos modos ¡resuelto!. Queda ahora decidir a quien otorgar la recompensa je je. Toledano tiene el 50% . Puedo otorgarte el otro 50% a ti si publicas una respuesta con la solución definitiva o el 100% a Toledano a condición de que edite la respuesta.

Comment: Por favor @MarcosGallardo crea una nueva respuesta para que sea esa la aceptada y merecidamente recibas la recompensa. Muchas gracias por tus aportes.

Comment: Es incluso mejor @MarcosGallardo, una vez aceptada tu respuesta yo edito la mía y le agrego además la información sobre cómo generar la clave que aparece en la respuesta de Jhd. Así queda la respuesta completa, con aportes de los y con el reconocimiento a quien lo merece

Comment: Me he permitido editar la respuesta, poniendo la imagen correcta de la conexión con Coda, ya que la opción que funcionaba era MySQL Server y no MySQL Server vía SSH. Saludos.

Answer (score 7):

En complemento a la [respuesta de @toledano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51893/16597).

- Conéctate al servidor remoto vía `SSH` de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  $ ssh -f user@remote.server -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N
  ```

  Esto creará un túnel el cual te permitirá conectarte al `Servidor MySQL Remoto` como si estuviera corriendo de forma local en el puerto `3307` (*puedes usar cualquier otro*). *Es recomendable usar un puerto distinto del `default` para evitar posibles conflictos con un servidor local.*
- Una vez establecido el túnel, abre `Coda` y para conectarte al servidor `MySQL` utiliza la opción `MySQL Server`, indicando:

  ```
  Server: localhost o 127.0.0.1
  Port: 3307 // El puerto indicado en el túnel
  User Name: user // Nombre de usuario de la DB remota
  Password: pass // Contraseña del usuario de la DB remota
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

- Generar llaves ssh

  `$ ssh-keygen`
- Copiar llave al servidor

  `$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub usuario@xxx.xxx.xx.xx`
- Instalar [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
- Configurar MySQL Workbench para establecer una conexión remota con la DB

  - Crear nueva conexión
  - En `connection name` poner el nombre que quieras
  - En Connection method elegir la opción `Standard TPC/IP over SSH`

Lo demás quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
SSH Hostname: ip_servidor:puerto
SSH Username: usuario
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port: 3306
Username: root (usuario MySQL)
Password: xxxxxx
```

Luego puedes pulsar el botón `Test Connection` si todo sale bien ya podrás conectarse desde MySQL Workbench. mas información sobre como hacer este tipo de conexión [acá](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html)

Comment: Gracias, pero necesito hacerlo con Coda, no con otra aplicación. ¿El motivo? Coda es un software de pago, que vale lo suyo y lo compré en gran parte para eso, no tiene sentido optar por un software alternativo ya que la idea era tener todo en un solo entorno de desarrollo: BD, PHP, HTML, JS, CSS... Coda lo hace, sólo que desde que mi ISP cambia a cada rato de IP tengo que entrar en mi cuenta de cPanel a autorizar la nueva IP.

Comment: ok. entonces tendrías que usar SSH, mira [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420791/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-using-coda-2) hay una posible solución para conectarse via ssh a MySQL a través de coda

Answer (score 3):

Mi respuesta va a ser más **teorica** que práctica (ya que de redes no sé mucho) y aclaro que puede ser o no una solución riesgosa dependiendo de la relevancia e importancia de tus datos ya que al conectarte a una VPN pública, muchas otras personas conectadas a los mismos servicios tendrían acceso a tu base de datos (claramente si conocen previamente conocen el host de esta)

Si tu *ISP (Internet Service Provider)* te provee de una IP dinámica que constatemente cambia como lo dices en el cuerpo de tu pregunta, creo que puedes hacer uso de una [VPN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_privada_virtual) (bien sea pública o privada) y así tendrás una IP estática la cual autorizar en tu *hosting compartido*.

Entonces, el procedimiento sería:

**1.** Conectarse a una VPN (pública o privada) que te provea siempre de una IP estática

**2.** Autorizar la anterior IP en tu *hosting compartido* (*Este paso solo se realizaría la primera vez*)

**3.** Realizar las transacciones necesarias (`INSERT`, `SELECT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc...) por medio de tu cliente (coda en este caso al parecer), cli, etc...

**4.** Volver al paso **1**, obviar el paso **2** si este ya se realizó

Yo útilizo [VPN one click](https://www.vpnoneclick.com/) (aclaro que no estoy haciendo ninguna publicidad a *x* o *y* producto que *x* o *y* VPN puedan ofrecer) esta tiene una versión gratis tanto como diferentes suscripciones mensuales

La descripción de la versión gratis dice:

> Use Free servers in Europe
>   **Uso de servidores gratis en Europa**
>
> Free for unlimited time on Windows/Linux/Android
>   **Gratis por tiempo ilimitado en Windows/Linux/Android**
>
> (Yo uso ubuntu y puedo conectarme a cerca de 18 países alrededor del mundo)
>
> Free for limited time on Mac/OSx/iOS
>   **Gratis por tiempo limitado en Mac/OSx/iOS**

También existe esta extensión para google chrome llamada [Hola VPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-free-vpn-hola/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=es-419).

Al igual que muchos otros servicios de estos tales como [hide.me](https://hide.me/es/software/mac) (**con un cliente gratuito para MAC**). El cual te da la [**posibilidad**](https://support.hide.me/hc/en-us/articles/200287789-Do-you-offer-dynamic-or-static-IP-addresses-) de siempre conectarte y reconectarte a un mismo lugar (oséase brindarte siempre la misma IP estática)

**CONCLUSIÓN:**

Solo puse unos ejemplos para aclarar la idea de solucionar tu problema a través de una VPN y una IP estática, tu puedes decidir y buscar la que más se ajuste a tus necesidades

[public vpn, búsqueda en google](https://www.google.com/search?q=public%20vpn)

**NOTA:**

No sé ni estoy seguro (porque apenas me lo cuestiono gracias a tu problema) si todos los anteriores servicios mencionado proveen una IP estática (así que los estaré probando durante tres(3) o cinco(5) días seguidos para actualizar mi respuesta)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Pero como dices: _ aclaro que puede ser o no una solución riesgosa dependiendo de la relevancia e importancia de tus datos_  La **seguridad de los datos es esencial** y en este caso de forma especial, pues los datos son el alma de esta aplicación y se maneja una gran cantidad de datos que no quisiera exponer autorizando IPs vía VPN, aparta de que no veo la forma de conectar el VPN a Coda para que asuma la IP del VPN. Es extraño que no haya podido lograrlo por SSH, aunque como he dicho en la pregunta, las indicaciones de Coda al respecto son pobres y confusas.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de nada: **no** tengo experiencia con este tema, así que, al igual que Jorius, mi respuesta es mas teórica que práctica.

Mirando la documentación de [cPanel sobre acceso remoto a MySql](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL), se indica que has de validar una IP **o un nombre DNS de host**.

Asi pues, se me antoja que la solución mas sencilla es utilizar algún servicio del tipo [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/) para crear un nombre de host que puedas actualizar, y utilizar dicho nombre para validar los accesos.

Hoy día, muchos de los *routers* que los ISP instalan soportan actualizar este tipo de servicios; además, hay clientes para casi todas las plataformas, o, en su defecto, se suele poder actualizar la IP del host mediante sencillas peticiones HTTP(s) GET.

Un problema que puedes tener es la *latencia*, el tiempo que tarden los DNS en actualizar tu IP. Ahí, es cosa de probar varios, hasta que encuentres el que te ofrezca mejores resultados.

Otro posible *inconveniente* es la cantidad de veces que tu ISP cambie tu IP. Si tu ruter soporta ese tipo de servicios, el *inconveniente* será menor. Si usas una aplicación en tu máquina, pues dependerá del intervalo en el que ésta compruebe si cambiaste de IP.

Comment: Esta respuesta también es una excelente alternativa.

Comment: @toledano Gracias por el +1, eres el único que sabe apreciar *la belleza de las cosas simples* ;-)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No lo he probado, pero creo que se notaría la lentitud. Ya conectándome con una IP normal autorizada, a veces iba lento y hasta provocaba crash en Coda, de vez en cuando (estamos hablando de un hosting compartido, lo cual tiene sus limitaciones, como es evidente). Con la solución encontrada, usando un túnel ssh, la velocidad es notable y hasta ahora, no ha habido ni un sólo crash. Incluso conectado a veces con una conexión desde el teléfono móvil que a veces es lenta, va de maravilla.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creí que ya lo habías solucionado. Te sugiero que pruebes mi propuesta: 1.- **no** depende de SSH; utiliza la conexión normal de mysql. 2.- **no** hay retraso de conexión. La conexión es directa, de tu máquina al servidor. 3.- **es** multidispositivo; se puede usar en cualquier máquina (solo 1 a la vez; para máquinas simultáneas, hay que **pagar** a NoIP.com o la que escojas).

Comment: Está solucionado. La recompensa es para agradecer a nuestro compañero @MarcosGallardo, ya que la recompensa anterior era sólo de 50 puntos y no se podía dividir. Era de justicia que la recibiese Toledano. Abriendo una nueva recompensa quiero agradecer la gran ayuda para resolver este problema crucial.