# codeigniter conexión a DB por tunel ssh

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3, ssh

estoy tratando de conectar desde codeigniter a una base de datos postgres externa a la cual debo acceder mediante un tunel ssh.
Tengo la típica cadena de conexión pero no sé como conectarlo por ssh.

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/19610

Answer (score 1):

Si el servidor de mysql está corriendo en el HostR por el puerto A (por ejemplo, el típico 3306) y tienes acceso por ssh al HostR, realiza un *port forwarding*

```
ssh -Nf usuarioR@HostR -L <puerto local>:<host>:<puertoA>
```

Por ejemplo

```
ssh -Nf usuario@34.34.34.34 -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

Donde `-L` permite pasar el tráfico del puesto 3306 remoto al 3306 local, `-N` no ejecuta ningún comando remoto y `-f` para que corra en *background*.

Después de esto ya puedes realizar tu conexión a dicha base de datos pero conectándote desde tu dirección IP `127.0.0.1` y tu puerto local `3306`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo mas cercano a lo que quieres.
[SSH Connection from CodeIgniter](https://gist.github.com/mbrowne/5101004)

Espero te sirva, nos comentas como te fue.

Saludos