# Conectarse a MySQL de mi hosting, no de localhost, a través de java

Tags: java

Actualmente me conecto a MySQL de localhost sin mayores problemas con los siguientes datos desde java:

```
private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
private String pass = "";
private String usuario = "root";
```

Quisiera que, en vez de conectarme a localhost lo hiciese directamente a la base de datos  de la web, pero no consigo acertar con la ruta que tengo que introducir en la variable `cadenaConexion`. He probado a poner la URL de la base de datos de la que se nutre mi web, pero me dice que no tengo acceso.

Comment: Tienes que habilitarlo en el mysql. Que SO tiene tu host linux o windows?

Comment: La verdad que no sabría responderte, voy a preguntar al soporte.

Comment: Tener acceso a una BBDD en remoto con el usuario root sin password es un gravisimo error de seguridad.

Comment: @Lithorell esa conexión es en local.

Comment: @JetLagFox Incluso en local es un error de seguridad

Comment: @JetLagFox Si vas a preguntarlo pregunta también si puedes conectarte en remoto a tu bb.dd. o si te pueden habilitar esa posibilidad si no puedes modificar la propiedad blind-address.

Comment: Vas a necesitar autorizar la dirección IP de tu conexión a Internet. Si dicha IP es siempre la misma es fácil hacerlo desde cPanel del hosting, si no, quizá sea necesario crear un túnel. [Esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886) creo que podrían serte útiles.

Answer (score 0):

Activar el acceso remoto del usuario ROOT (no es una buena práctica por seguridad)

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Crear un usuario para conectarse en remoto:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';    
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

Comentar el la siguiente propiedad del archivo my.cnf file, en linux está en  /etc/mysql/my.cnf y en windows suele estar en tu Carpeta_Instalacion_Mysql ejemplo C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\ y el archivo se llama my.ini.

Cambia:
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Por:
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Reinicia el MySQL