# Como crear una conexion remota desde mi Mysql Workbench a Codeanywhere

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, ssh

Tengo un problema, he intentado conectarme de forma remota a la base de datos que tengo en un contenedor en la plataforma **CodeAnywhere**, dicho contenedor usa como S.O **Ubuntu 16.04**.

He estado leyendo y pues al parecer para conectarme debo usar esta ventana que ofrece **WorckBench** para establecer una conexion remota con la base de datos que tengo en dicha plataforma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad soy nuevo en esto y no se como llenar esos campo de tal forma que me funcione. Necesito trabajar en esa base de datos, ya que la solución que ofrece es abrirla con PhpmyAdmin y es una IDE poco amigable...

Espero su ayuda amigos :)

Comment: Dado que la conexión es remota, deberás autorizar constantemente la IP del equipo desde el cual intentes conectar, lo cual no es siempre tan evidente, porque las IP suelen cambiar. La solución pasa por abrir un túnel ssh y crear llaves públicas y privadas de conexión. Creo que el hilo de la pregunta **[MySQL: ¿Es posible una conexión remota sin tener que autorizar mi dirección IP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967)** te puede ayudar, aunque el contexto sea algo diferente.

Comment: Gracias amigo, con lo que me mandaste complemente con lo que necesitabas, gracias a ti y al compañero wchiquito por su ayuda...

Comment: De nada. Si te ha ayudado puedes darle un voto a favor a la respuesta aceptada y a la otra, cuando tengas la puntuación suficiente. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intente la siguiente configuración en MySQL Workbench:

[image: MySQL Codeanywhere]

Mayores detalles en [Codeanywhere Documentation :: Container](http://docs.codeanywhere.com/connections/container.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu comentario, me ayudo demasiado para tener idea de como llenar los campos de dicha ventana , me funciono de maravilla :)