# Acceso remoto a MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buenas.

Llevo un tiempo buscando información de como acceder remotamente a MySQL y he encontrado muchos tutoriales (alguno de ellos en Stackoverflow) pero después de haberlos probado todos sigo sin poder acceder.

El servidor donde tengo alojada la base de datos es un VPS al cual tengo acceso total, y el lugar desde donde intento acceder a dicha base de datos es un alojamiento de un hosting compartido.

Estas son las cosas que he hecho:

1) En el archivo my.cnf he comentado la línea skip-external-locking y he añadido la línea "bind-address = 0.0.0.0".

```
# The following options will be passed to all MariaDB clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MariaDB server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#skip-external-locking <---------------------------- ESTA LINEA
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 <---------------------------- ESTA LINEA

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking
```

2) He añadido una regla a la lista de iptables del Firewall escribiendo el comando "iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT" en la consola del servidor.

```
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
39       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
```

3) He entrado en phpMyAdmin como root y he modificado dicha cuenta para cambiar el nombre del servidor a "%" y le he dado "ALL PRIVILEGES".

```
Nombre de usuario   Nombre del servidor Contraseña  Privilegios globales    Conceder
root                %                   Sí          ALL PRIVILEGES         Sí
```

4) Una vez hecho todo eso y tras haber reiniciado MySQL y Apache, pruebo a conectarme a la base de datos mediante este código php y no hace nada, se queda pensando:

```
$hostname_vps = "aqui la IP del VPS"; (también he probado con el dominio)
$username_vps = "root";
$password_vps = "aqui la contraseña para la cuenta root";
$database_vps = "aqui el nombre de la base de datos a la que quiero acceder";
$vps = mysql_pconnect($hostname_vps, $username_vps, $password_vps) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_vps, $vps);
```

Esta conexión funciona si la página está alojada en el VPS por lo que los datos aquí incluídos son correctos.
También he probado con el programa HeidiSQL y la conexión se realiza correctamente.
Pero si lo intento desde la página alojada en otro servidor nada, no hay respuesta.

¿Hago algo mal? Ya no se que más hacer...

**EDITO**:

Al final resulta que el proveedor de la otra parte no deja que yo pueda conectarme a una base de datos que no está en su alojamiento...

Lo que he hecho supongo que funciona pero con este proveedor nunca lo sabré.

Gracias a todos por las respuestas, siento las molestias.

Comment: Normalmente no es tan complicado, solo con la IP+puerto y las credenciales bastaría. Prueba a descomentar: "skip-external-locking" y conectar desde tu máquina local, con **mysql worbench** por ejemplo.

Comment: Nunca había probado el MySQL Workbench pero lo acabo de descargar y puedo entrar a mi servidor. Aunque antes de hacerlo me sale un aviso: Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.1.30). En todo caso si puedo acceder desde este programa porque no puedo hacerlo desde el otro alojamiento? Será cosa del proveedor?

Comment: El aviso que te sale en el programa es habitual, digamos que no esta probado con versiones recientes de mysql/mariadb. Si puedes conectar y visualizar la BD remota parece que el problema no esta en esta parte, será cosa de la parte desde la que tratas de acceder.

Comment: Gracias, me pondré en contacto con el proveedor de la otra parte a ver que sucede.

Comment: Saludos RoD, ¿[por casualidad viste esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967)? Dado que es un acceso remoto, podrías hacerlo mediante un túnel, usando llaves privadas y públicas.

Comment: "Pero si lo intento desde la página alojada en otro servidor nada, no hay respuesta." ¿¿¿En el servidor web tienes permisos para conectarte remotamente a otros servidores???, por ejemplo, Hostinger con cuentas gratuitas no permite conexiones remotas a bases de datos.

Comment: Otra cosa que también tienes que configurar es el permiso para darle acceso a tu IP pública y se pueda conectar a la BD

Comment: Reynaldo, el proveedor no es Hostinger pero he contactado con ellos y me dicen que tampoco permiten conexiones remotas a bases de datos (ni de entrada, ni de salida), así que es eso...

Answer (score -1):

Hola el servidor está montado en tu maquina local mente o es un servidor físico
Para poder ayudarte 
Si es local sigue estos pasos

1) Abre o instala **MySQL Workbench** (Para esta forma de resolver tu problema se necesita ese Gestor)

2) Abre tu **connection** si no acabas de instalar solo crea uno nuevo

3) ve a **MANAGEMENT** Y elige **users and privileges**

4) elije un **usuario** (puedes usar **root** el que está por defecto) o crea uno nuevo

5) debajo de **Details for account root@%** (o nombreDelUsuarioQueEligiste@%)

6) Busca la pestaña **Login** esta de primero

7) donde dice **Limit to hosts Matching** borra lo que contenga creo que tiene por defecto **And_wildcards may be used**

8) escribe **%**

9) aplica cambios dando click en el botón **Apply**

Listo 
Recuerda si que quieres acceder de otra maquian es por tu **IP**  asignate una **IP** antes de probar 
Cambias el l**ocalhost o 127.0.0.1**  en tu conexión por tu **IP**  y listo
Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Eso ya lo hice en el tercer paso desde la interfaz de phpMyAdmin. Cuando entro en MySQL Workbench ya me sale como tu dices. Al final ha resultado ser un problema de permisos del proveedor así que no puedo hacer nada. Gracias de todas formas.