# ¿Cómo puedo hacer copia de seguridad de mi base de datos remota (MySQL) en mi equipo local mediante ssh?

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh

Este es mi contexto:

#### Entorno remoto:

- Base de datos remota MySQL alojada en un hosting compartido
- Dominio con un certificado SSL (gratis) instalado. Se accede mediante `https`

#### Entorno local:

- Equipo con sistema operativo Mac OSX
- Tiene configurado un tunel de acceso a la base de datos mediante llaves públicas/privadas (por ejemplo desde mi IDE puedo acceder conectar sin problemas a la base de datos). Esto lo he podido hacer gracias a las respuestas a la pregunta: [MySQL: ¿Es posible una conexión remota sin tener que autorizar mi dirección IP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967)

### Lo que quiero hacer

En el entorno remoto yo tengo ejecutando un script ssh que me hace una copia periódica de la base de datos (dos veces a la semana mediante un cron). Esa copia de seguridad se hace en una carpeta del mismo entorno remoto.

Pero quisiera saber cómo puedo ejecutar esa copia en mi entorno local. No sé si tendría que adaptar el mismo script que ejecuto remotamente o si tengo que escribir un script diferente. No sé si tendría que usar el usuario y clave de la base de datos como en el script remoto, o si puedo usar las llaves pública/privada  que ya tengo configuradas.

No conozco casi nada de ssh, este script lo encontré investigando y pude adaptarlo y hacerlo funcionar remotamente:

```
#!usr/bin/path/backup.sh

# List of databases to be backed up separated by space
dblist="mydb"
user="myuser"
pass="mypass********"

# Directory for backups
backupdir=/my/path

# Number of versions to keep
numversions=4

# Full path for MySQL hotcopy command
# Please put credentials into /root/.my.cnf
#hotcopycmd=/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
hotcopycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump -u$user -p$pass --lock-tables --databases"

# Create directory if needed
mkdir -p "$backupdir"
if [ ! -d "$backupdir" ]; then
   echo "Invalid directory: $backupdir"
   exit 1
fi

# Hotcopy begins here
echo "Dumping MySQL Databases..."
RC=0
for database in $dblist; do
   echo
   echo "Dumping $database ..."
   mv "$backupdir/$database.gz" "$backupdir/$database.0.gz" 2> /dev/null
   $hotcopycmd $database | gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz"

   RC=$?
   if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
     continue;
   fi

   # Rollover the backup directories
   rm -fr "$backupdir/$database.$numversions.gz" 2> /dev/null
   i=$numversions
   while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
     mv "$backupdir/$database.`expr $i - 1`.gz" "$backupdir/$database.$i.gz" 2> /dev/null
     i=`expr $i - 1`
   done
done

if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "MySQL Dump failed!"
   exit $RC
else
   # Hotcopy is complete. List the backup versions!
   ls -l "$backupdir"
   echo "MySQL Dump is complete!"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: No creo que haga falta ssh, podes copiar los backups con rsync y luego ejecutarlos, o usar directamente el mysqldump desde la computadora local en la remota y ejecutarlos en la base local

Comment: @Sacha agradezco tu comentario. La idea de `rsync` me abre una ventana que no veía. En efecto solo me interesa tener en local una copia de la base de datos (en forma de archivos), no es para ejecutarla o usarla en local, la BD solo la uso remotamente y quiero tener copia en local para mayor seguridad ante cualquier catástrofe en el host. La BD tiene información de muchos años de trabajo y no quiero confiarla ciegamente a un servicio de hosting por más garantías que ellos den de backups.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te pude ser de ayuda, te daria un ejemplo pero la verdad es que las veces que he usado el rsync son contadas y siempre me cuesta varios intentos salirme con el comando que funciona.

Comment: @Sacha efectivamente una buena solución a este problema es seguir haciendo las copias en el hosting remoto y luego sincronizar las copias ya hechas en local con `rsync`.  Lo he probado y funciona. Agradezco que redactes una respuesta para darlo por resuelto y pueda ser útil a futuros usuarios. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este problema en cuestion puede solucionarse de manera sencilla utilizando la herramienta rsync, la cual se utiliza para copiar archivos por protocolo ssh.
 Simplemente podes crear un archivo bash con la linea de comando:

```
rsync usuario@host:ruta-remota ruta-local
```

Y luego agregarlo al cron, para que periodicamente sincronice los backups.