# ¿Cómo autenticar un script mediante mi llave privada para sincronizar archivos remotos en local?

Tags: ssh, rsync

Tengo en mi hosting remoto unos archivos que son copias de seguridad de mi base de datos, los cuales se crean periódicamente mediante un cron.

Ahora yo quiero tener sincronizado ese directorio remoto con un directorio local.

Manualmente el comando me funciona bien:

```
rsync --progress --partial -avz my-user@mi-host-or-ip:/home/my-user/public_html/.backup/test "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Downloads/test" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms
```

Sólo que al hacerlo así me pide cada vez la contraseña del servidor remoto.

Pero si intento hacer esto no me funciona:

```
rsync --progress --partial -avz my-user@mi-host-or-ip:/home/my-user/public_html/.backup/test "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Downloads/test" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms
```

Lo que trato de pasar aquí `~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms` es la ruta de mi archivo que contiene la clave privada.

La clave privada funciona, yo la uso para crear un túnel entre MySQL remota y mi equipo local y puedo conectar sin problema.

Pensé que podría usar esa misma clave para `rsync` pero no me funciona. El error que me da es el siguiente:

> ```
> Unexpected local arg: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Downloads/test
> If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
> rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1388) [Receiver=3.1.3]
> ```

¿Puedo usar mi clave privada para eso?  ¿Cómo tendría que escribir el comando? Si no se puede de esa manera, ¿de qué otra forma podría autenticarme sin tener que escribir la contraseña cada vez y evitando tener la contraseña escrita en un archivo?

La idea es usar el comando con un cron para sincronizar periódicamente esos archivos.

En mi entorno estoy usando:

- Mac OSX
- `rsync` actualizado instalado desde Homebrew
- Remotamente es un hosting compartido

Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cómo puedo hacer copia de seguridad de mi base de datos remota (MySQL) en mi equipo local mediante ssh?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/181735/29967)

Comment: por clave te referis a public key file o password del user remoto? si es el public key, tiene además un "passphrase" ? rsync debería tomar la configuración del ssh (y si tu host local está entre los authorized_keys entrar sin pedir clave, salvo que haya problema de permisos en el servidor). `ssh usuario@hostremoto -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms` entra sin pedir clave?