# Problema de conexión remota con la BD MySql en CPANEL

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, cpanel, mysqldb

He tenido ciertos problemas al tratar de conectarme de un Servidor A (Servidor local) a un Servidor B (Hosting Pago).  Hasta hoy, que me surge el problema porque no realiza la debida conexión, en el momento en que se lanza la petición al servidor el Cliente se queda sin esperar respuesta por lo que me genera un error (Bueno, mas bien una respuesta y no un error como tal):

> Error al tratar de conectarse con MySql debido al error **Connection timed out**

Este es mi código para realizar la conexion desde PHP:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('xxx.xxxxx.com', 'user_xxxxxx', 'clave_xxxx', 'db_xxxxx');
  if($mysqli->connect_error):
  {
    echo "Error al tratar de conectarse con MySql debido al error ".$mysqli->connect_error;
  }
  endif;


?>
```

Ademas, de que he intentado realizar la conexion desde `MySql Workbench` y  `SQLyog Ultimate` y ambos retornan un error `2003`.

En mi servidor pago tengo el comodin que permite las conexiones remotas hacia `MySql`[image: Comodin]

**Nota:** todo funcionaba bien hasta hace unas 4 horas aproximadamente. Inclusive, aquellos dominios donde apuntaba hacia una direccion del hosting y estando dentro de la misma maquina, presenta el mismo patron. Por lo que procedi a utilizar el `localhost` en vez de la direccion del hosting o la IP y de esta manera lo solucione, pero en este caso no puedo realizar eso, debido a que son accesos remotos que si o si se requieren.

Comment: Para conexiones remotas la IP o el rango de IP debe estar autorizada, de lo contrario no será posible conectarse, por motivos de seguridad.  Esto es particularmente problemático cuando el ISP cambia constantemente la IP de tu conexión local. Una posibilidad es usar llaves públicas/privadas y crear un tunel para conectarte si tener que autorizar la IP cada vez que cambies. [Puedes consultar esta pregunta al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967). Es lo que uso ahora para conectarme a mi db desde mi equipo local. ¿El código PHP que muestras está en tu equipo local?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano Si, esta en mi equipo local.

Comment: Si la IP o rango de IP actual del equipo local no están autorizadas en el servidor remoto no podrás conectarte a la base de datos desde tu equipo local, a no ser que tengas un túnel. En la pregunta enlazada en mi anterior comentario hay más detalles sobre ese asunto.

Comment: voy a echar un vistaso, pero me surge una dud y es el porque hasta hace poco funcionaba y ahora no lo hace? (hablamos de 7 u 8 meses que llevaba funcionando con normalidad) cuando es una IP a la que le asigné un comodin para que permita las peticiones que se realicen de forma remota.

Comment: No sabría decirte. Verifica que las credenciales no hayan cambiado: nombre de usuario, contraseña, etc. Me extraña que funcione así sin más, por seguridad los hostings tienen restringido el acceso remoto a la base de datos para IP no autorizadas. Al menos en mi caso (Bluehost)  es así. Si revisas el log de errores en el servidor quizá te informe con más detalle sobre la naturaleza del error que impide la conexión.

Comment: Ya lo he revisado, y tampoco me genera los respectivos logs en el servidor, por lo que se me hace aun mas extraño.

Comment: ¿Y el log de errores local del archivo PHP que intenta la conexión tampoco dice nada? ¿Estás  revisando el log de errores correcto?

Comment: Efectivamente, ni en mi maquina ni en el servidor pago genera el respectivo archivo log. Porque hasta hace poco realizaba conexiones remotas y si ingresaba un valor erroneo se generaba automaticamente. Ademas, si pruebo apuntando hacia un lugar inexistente tampoco lo hace.

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es contactar con el soporte técnico del hosting... o esperar un poco y reintentar.  A veces pasa que teniendo todo bien configurado deja de funcionar porque el servidor está caído o porque te bloquean temporalmente la dirección IP debido a demasiadas conexiones fallidas seguidas. Al cabo de minutos / horas , reinicio de router, del equipo ... todo vuelve a la normalidad.

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema ?