# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a una base de datos atravez de PHP, usando PDO con mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¡Buenas!, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos que cree en infinityfree.net, es decir, tengo mi cuenta donde iría el sitio web (cosas como el panel de control, el nombre de usuario, el servidor FTP el puerto, la contraseña y demás están aquí), a una de las cuentas le cree una base de datos MySQL, una vez creada con el panel de control me manda a un sitio donde aparece información como:

MySQL DB Name, MySQL User Name, MySQL Password y MySQL Host Name.

La forma que uso para conectarme es la siguiente:

```
<?php

    //Función que conectara a la base de datos que necesitemos.
    function conectar($host,$DB,$user,$pass){

        try {

            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$DB;charset = UTF-8",$user,$pass);
            return $conexion;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
            echo $error;
            return false;

        }

    }

?>
```

A la función conectar le paso los parámetros que me dan como información en la base de datos que cree, así:

```
                     //Estos parametros son strings pero reemplazados con los valores reales que me dieron como información
$conexion = conectar(MySQL Host Name, MySQL DB Name, MySQL User Name, MySQL Password);
```

El caso es que para probar que podía usar esta base de datos, escribir o eliminar información y crear tablas etc, intente conectarme a ella atravez de xampp desde localhost (Archivos locales), pero cuando intenta conectarse a la base de datos se demora cargando un buen rato el sitio, para que luego me aparezca el siguiente error PDO:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.

Comment: ¿Dices que intentas conectarte desde XAMPP en local ... a la base de datos remota? No entiendo muy bien, si te quieres conectar desde local tienes que dar permisos (en la base de datos remota, vía cPanel por ejemplo) para que acepte conexiones de esa IP local. Además no entiendo por qué quieres conectarte desde local y no directamente en el sitio, subiendo el script PHP al servidor remoto y ejecutándolo vía URL.

Comment: Como digo, lo queria hacer para probar (Sin tener que esperar a que la pagina suba los archivos y se muestre), ya que demora una media hora para poder montar la pagina entera por primera vez,  para asegurarme de una vez que la conexión esta correcta y todo.

Comment: Si dura media hora para subir un script php que no pesa nada, la conexión a la base de datos desde un lugar remoto entonces va a ser eterna, si es que te lo permite. Como te digo, en los hosting más o menos decentes (de pago), para conectar a la base de datos [tienes que autorizar la IP desde la cual te vas a conectar, o bien usar llaves públicas / privadas, en caso de que quieras manipular la base de datos desde tu equipo local](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967). Si es un hosting gratuito dudo que te permitan tantas libertades, ya que suelen ser muy limitados y restrictivos.

Comment: Enrealidad solo se demora eso para "actualizar", no para subir, para subir se demora 1 segundo  o menos, intento borrar el cache varias vecez para ver si ya se ve la pagina, pero resulta que cuando montas por primera vez una cuenta y a la vez montas por primera vez archivos en ella, lo que demora no es la carga, si no  la actualización de estas. Luego la actualización de esta es mucho mas rapida, en 5 segundos puede haberse actualizado toda la pagina con los archivos actualizados.

Comment: Entiendo... pero tecnicamente si puedo crear bases de datos en este hosting, ¿si intento conectar a ella desde la pagina ya subida en el hosting gratuito, este problema deberia solucionarse cierto??

Comment: La mejor manera de probar la base de datos es subiendo el PHP que se conecta a ella al servidor y probar a ejecutar ese archivo. Conectarte desde XAMPP en local lo veo muy muy complicado sobre todo si es hosting gratuito. Y si es para trabajar en serio desde local en la base de datos remota, vas a tener que abrir un tunel entre la BD y tu equipo local y crear llaves públicas / privadas. En el enlace anterior ya en la pregunta narré varios pasos del calvario que supuso eso al principio (y hablo de un hosting de pago). Tenía que hacerlo funcionar porque diariamente necesito conectar desde local.

Comment: Vaya, que pedazo de código solo para conectarse a una base de datos de un servidor diferente desde localhost xd, quiero darte como respuesta, sin embargo una cosa mas... no recuerdo cual es el comando o función que se usa para encontrar la ruta "root", donde se encuentra el index.php, podrías decirmela?.

Comment: ¿La ruta donde se encuentra el `index.php` en tu sitio remoto quieres decir? Generalmente es el directorio llamado `public_html`, aunque algunos hosting la cambian por `www` o cosas así, pero en casi todos es `public_html` Y, lo del otro asunto no es un pedazo de código, lo que hace posible la conexión es solamente esto: `ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 usuario@servidor.remoto` que hace el tunel entre el servidor remoto y el local. Con eso y teniendo llaves públicas y privadas ya te puedes conectar a la base de datos remota desde cualquier cliente, incluyendo XAMPP.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, apenas aparezca el boton para dar como respuesta la daré como respuesta. Aunque no, no hablo de la ruta remota, hablo de la ruta ya cuando la pagina se encuentra en el server, si no mal recuerdo hay una función en PHP que te permite extraer como un string la ruta raiz de tu archivo principal de manera dinámica independientemente de la dirección en la que te encuentres.

Comment: Ah, ¿te refieres a la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo actual de PHP? En PHP [hay varias funciones para eso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.filesystem.php), dependiendo de si quieres la ruta absoluta, la ruta relativa del archivo, etc.

Comment: Dos actualizaciones:

Comment: 1-) Funciona correctamente la base de datos en el sitio web ya subido
2-) No te preocupes por la ruta, ya encontre 3 maneras de encontrarla, de antemano muchas gracias!, encontre la manera de: dirname(), y tambien se puede poniendo "./", para acceder a la ruta correctamente.