# Client with this ip ************* is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, azure

tratando de conectar worckbench con azure mysql server, me sale este erro a pesar de:
contar con el certificado, acceder con el usuario root de dicho servidor. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Alguna información adicional?, puedo lograr conexión siguiendo los pasos indicados en [Azure Database for MySQL: Use MySQL Workbench to connect and query data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-workbench) y [Configure SSL connectivity in your application to securely connect to Azure Database for MySQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl), la documentación está en inglés.

Comment: Si es una conexión remota, debes autorizar la IP desde la cual te estás conectando, o puedes crear un túnel ( [ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967) ).

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias, si, no había autorizado el cliente.

Comment: Si el cliente tiene una IP fija la puedes autorizar y listo, pero si la IP cambia tendrás que crear un túnel y conectar usando llaves públicas/privadas. Es la forma más segura de hacerlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, si tenían ip fija con eso jaló bien.